# como fazer uma classe não criar um objeto automaticamente em python

Tags: python

eu tenho um código

```
import tkinter as tk
window=tk.Tk()
class exampleClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        window.mainloop()
        pass
```

mas eu não quero que essa classe seja criada.
o python ele cria a classe mesmo sem ter definido ela.
isso serve tipo pra fazer uma classe que contem funções exemplo.

```
class mathf:
    def getFileTxt(src=""):
        f=open(src,"r+")
        f.seek(0)
        txt=f.read()
        txt=txt.strip("\n")
        txt=txt.replace("\n","")
        f.close()
        return txt
print(mathf.getFileTxt("testeFile.txt"))
```

só que eu não quero isso . pq se não da erro no meu código
pq eu tenho uma classe que tem varias variáveis, que só podem ser acessadas quando e chamada

```
class Tile:
    id="TesteTile"
    name=""
    collidible=False
    drawEvent=""
Tiles=[Tile()]
def getTile(id=""):
    i=0
    while i<len(Tiles):
        if not Tiles[i].id==id:
            i+=1
        else : 
            return i
Tiles.clear()
class TileGame:
    tile=Tile()
    def __init__(self,idt=""):
        self.tile=Tiles[getTile(idt)]
```

pq não existe o tile que possui esse tileId de: "".
como que eu faço pra não criar essa classe?
quando vc cria uma classe em python. o python já cria um objeto com base nessa classe. e vc pode fazer objetos com funções com isto:

```
class mathf:
    def getFileTxt(src=""):
        f=open(src,"r+")
        f.seek(0)
        txt=f.read()
        f.close()
        return txt
print(mathf.getFileTxt("testeFile.txt"))
```

sem definir um objeto. mas se for assim. meu programa ele cria um erro. pq ele usa o item id para buscar um item. mas não existe um item com o tile id de "", e ele não acha e ai da o erro. pq ele crio um ItemGame

Comment: Na descrição do que precisa o padrão de projeto Singleton pode ajudar, pode criar  1 (um) ou mais.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei se eu entendi corretamente, mas o Python só cria um novo objeto de classe (ou de função) quando a definição da classe (ou função) é "executada".

Isso quer dizer que se a função ou classe estiver dentro de um if, por exemplo, o objeto de classe ou função só é criado se a condição for verdadeira. Portanto:

```
if False:
    class ExampleClass:
        pass

# NameError:
a = ExampleClass()
```

Causa NameError, por outro lado:

```
if True:
    class ExampleClass:
        pass

# OK:
a = ExampleClass()
```

Roda normalmente.